# Why I lose performance if I use LINQ on MongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, mongodb

This is the situation. I have a Domain object `Product` like this...

```
[DataContract]
public class Product : IStorableEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String RemoteId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String LanguageId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
    ETC..ETC...
}
```

into my repository layer I have the following method.

```
public IEnumerable<TElement> Read()
{
    var mongoCollection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TElement>(_partitionName);
    return mongoCollection.AsQueryable<TElement>();

}
```

With this method I want to expose via LINQ my repository layer without exporting information about technology.

In this way I can do this:

```
var _repository = new MyRepositoryFactory<Product>(); 
var result = _repository.Read().Where(p=>p.RemoteId == "1")
```

this query it takes 1 or 2 milliseconds.

instead...

```
var _repository = new MyRepositoryFactory<Product>();
var result = _repository.Read().Where(p=>p.RemoteId == "29000")
```

**it takes 2800 milliseconds!!!**

I have correctly created a unique index with the command

`db.products.ensureIndex({"RemoteId":1, unique:true})`

*NB: Yes, I have also rebuilt the indexes with `.reIndex()` command*

Here the strange thing...
Avoiding LINQ and modifying the repository method in...

```
public IEnumerable<TElement> Read(string remoteId)
{
    var mongoCollection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TElement>(_partitionName);
      var query = Query<TElement>.EQ(p => p.RemoteId, remoteId);
    return mongoCollection.Find(query);
}
```

if then I invoke the method whit the same id before..

```
var _repository = new MyMongoRepository<Product>();
var result = _repository.Read("29000")
```

it takes 1 or 2 milliseconds. WHY??

Why with the first approach do I have a performance degradation as the id increases instead with the second is not it?

Ps. Erm... really sorry for my english

Comment: did you run the where(29000) query more than once?

Comment: Try changing `IEnumerable<TElement>` to `IQueryable<TElement>`. I believe your code causes the entire collection to be retrieved and then the `where` clause is executed locally against the retrieved data.

Comment: Yes WiredPrairie! It works! 2 beers for you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As WiredPrainie stated in comments you should use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable` otherwise the whole collection will be retrieved.
Read this guide carefully
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: Nothing about IQueryable on the entire docs site https://www.google.com.au/#q=iqueryable+site:mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0&gws_rd=cr,ssl

Comment: Try "AsQueryable" friend.